# how to avoid duplicate slugs when saving a friendly url

Tags: php

sorry but I'm new, a true apprentice of the php. Sorry for my English, but I'm Italian.

I'm trying to figure out how to avoid saving duplicates in the slug column of my database when I save.

When I save a new page I check in the database if I find a line with the slug I would like to save. If it is not there, I proceed without problems. If there is instead I would like to save it by adding "1" and then "2" and so on.

I'v tried with

```
$string="example-2";
$string= str_replace("-", "", $string);
$string=filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

and works but but if I save a slug like this:

```
$string="my2example-2";
```

It' doesn't work

I can not understand how to do in php to analyze the string and understand if there is already a number at the end of the string.

Example:

the first time i save a sulg 'example'.

Then I want to save a second page with the "exemple" slug, so I look in the database, I find that there is "exemple" then I add "-1" to my string and save it as "example-1".

Then I want to save "exemple" again, I find it exists "example". So i have to search to look for "exemple-1"
How to do it?

and than how do I then identify what number I have arrived to save
"exemple-2"?

thanks

Comment: if the slug is there, also fetch the text. then take the last number by regex or exploding or whatever (depending on your text), and simply proceed with the saving procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the original slug then each time you check the DB for an existing entry append -1, -2 etc until you get no matches.

```
$i = 1;
$baseSlug = $slug;

function slug_exists($slug) {
    $query = "SELECT `slug` FROM `table` WHERE `slug`=?";
    $stmt = $dbl->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $slug);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

while(slug_exist($slug)){
    $slug = $baseSlug . "-" . $i++;        
}

// Save slug in DB
```

Comment: This can be slow because of multiple database queries. Especially if DB is not on the same machine and must be accessed via network.

Comment: Agreed - it is not the most efficient method but it is arguably the easiest to understand for a novice developer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying your database to determine if slug `example` exists, you can get all slugs that starts with `example`:

`SELECT slug FROM table WHERE slug LIKE 'example%';`

Then you just need to filter out values that aren't `example` or `example-[0-9]+`. In some databases you can do it directly, but you can also do it with regex in PHP. Last thing is to find slug with highest number (for example by sorting first), and incrementing the numeric part.

Ensure that you're using [natural sort ordering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

**Example from above link:**

```
<?php
$array1 = $array2 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");

asort($array1);
echo "Standard sorting\n";
print_r($array1);

natsort($array2);
echo "\nNatural order sorting\n";
print_r($array2);
?>
```

**results:**

```
Standard sorting
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
    [2] => img2.png
)

Natural order sorting
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```

Comment: can you explain better how to do this? "Last thing is to find slug with highest number (for example by sorting first), and incrementing the numeric part."

Comment: Which part makes you trouble?